# "$.get" for retrieving information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to get a simple javascript popup script going anytime the database is updated in real-time. I'm not sure as to what to do next, because I'm still a newbie with jQuery and ajax, but the following code is what I have right now:

PHP MySQL query page:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','mydb');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"mydb");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM incoming_calls";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    //$callArray = array('phonenumber' => $row['phone_number'], 'id' => $row['phone_login_id']);
    if(!empty($row)) {
    $number = $row['phone_number'];
    }
}

$sql="SELECT Username, Password FROM tblUsers WHERE PhoneHome='$number' OR PhoneCell='$number' OR PhoneWork='$number'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $userArray = array("username" => $row['Username'], "password" => $row['Password']);
    //echo json_encode($userArray);
}
    echo json_encode($userArray);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Phone calls</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getCall(){
  $.get("phonecall.php", function(data){
    var loginInfo = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    var user = loginInfo.username;
    var pass = loginInfo.password;
    $('#username').html(user);
    $('#password').html(pass);
  });

/*$.getJSON("phonecall.php", function(data){
    for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
        $('#username').html(data);
  }
 });*/
}
setInterval(getCall,5000);
</script>

<div id="username"></div>
<div id="password"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

One of the problems I am having is that when there are 2 or more users with the same phone number for say like a house phone, depending on where the json_encode is, will either return the last entry in the table, or return nothing at all. If the json_encode is in the while loop, I can check the console, it says the information is being retrieved, but something must not be right with my "$.get" syntax to allow more than one entry to be displayed. Any ideas?

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need this `mysqli_select_db($con,"mydb");` you're already selecting it here `$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','mydb');`

Answer (score 2):

You're only ever saving one row of data:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $userArray = array("username" etc...
             ^^^^---here
```

If you have multiple rows of data, each row you fetch will overwrite the previous row in $userArray.

You probably want

```
$userArray[] = array("username" etc...
          ^^---- note these
```

so you're creating an array of results.

You'll also have to modify your JS code to accept an array of arrays, since right now you only handle one username/password.

Comment: I've tried using the [] brackets, but then it just doesn't work whatsoever, and I'm not sure what to do in my JS code to make it accept an array of arrays. Any help on this is appreciated!

Comment: `loginInfo[0].username`, basically. but if you want to return multiple name records, you'd need to handle that.

Comment: you have something like fetchAll, with that you can store it in $userArray, how ever if you only have one row it wont work

Comment: If you need to diplay several users, you need to plan it in your HTML. Right now, your HTML is for one user only...